# EventEmitter in shared service's constructor doens't emit data

Tags: angular, eventemitter

I have a `HomeCmp` and `Shared Service`.

Look at the `shared service`'s constructor. I have manually set 'Guest' string and trying to emit `UserModel object`. But it doesn't receive object in `HomeCmp`'s `ngOnInit`.

If you click the button, it will work. any suggestion?

How can I show `Guest` string when I run the app through `EventEmitter`.

**service.ts**

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {UserModel} from 'app/models';
export class NavService {

  user:EventEmitter<UserModel>=new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor')

    userDetail=new UserModel();
    userDetail.name="guest";
    userDetail.loggedIn=false;
    console.log(userDetail);
    this.user.emit(userDetail);
  }

  ngOnInit(){ // just wanted to check if it could help or not. I know it belongs to Component's life cycle.
    console.log('onit')
  }

   setUserDetail(str)
  {
    console.log('SetUserDetail started');
    userDetail.name=str;
    userDetail.loggedIn=true;
    this.user.emit(userDetail);
  }

  getUserDetail()
  {
    return this.user;
  }
}
```

**Homecmp.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NavService} from '../services/NavService';
import {UserModel} from 'app/models';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div>User object:</div>

  {{userData|json}}
  <button (click)="setuser()">Click</button>
  `
})
export class HomeCmp {
  constructor(authService:NavService){
        this.authService=authService; 

    }
  setuser()
  {
   this.authService.setUserDetail("micronyks");
  }


     ngOnInit(){
                console.log('here is userInfo');
                this.subscription = this.authService.getUserDetail()
                                    .subscribe((item) => {this.userData=item;
                                                          console.log('Finally i m working');
                                                          console.log(this.userInfo);

                                                         });
     }

    ngOnDestroy() {

    }
}
```

**models.ts**

```
export class UserModel()
{
 private name:string;
 private loggedIn:boolean=false;
}
```

**[working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kKDYbmHpDazQQ9h8SH0M?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular creates a `NavService` instance and while doing this, the constructor is executed and the event fired. As next step Angular creates an instance of the `HomeCmp` component and passes the `NavService` in. Then in `HomeCmp`s constructor a listener for `user:EventEmitter` is registered. After this registration no event is emitted and therefore not recieved anymore.

What you want to do is to delay firing the event. I assume your situation is only for testing purposes and in practice firing an event in the constructor isn't necessary anyway.

For testing purposes you can just wrap `this.user.emit(userDetail);` in a `setTimeOut`

```
setTimeOut(() => this.user.emit(userDetail), 1);
```

**[Answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/UdyfPnOknWN2EwGqHkEm?p=preview)**

Comment: Not sure what you try to accomplish. Your `EventEmitter` is `user` but you are subscribing to `getUserDetail()`. I guess you want http://plnkr.co/edit/UdyfPnOknWN2EwGqHkEm?p=preview

Comment: Right, looked at the wrong place. So is it now working as expected or what is not yet working. I fixed the `console.log()` in `HomeComp.onNgInit()` where a field was printed that doesn't exist. http://plnkr.co/edit/UdyfPnOknWN2EwGqHkEm?p=preview

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/kKDYbmHpDazQQ9h8SH0M?p=preview. Is it correct way? Just look at the `app.component.ts` file.

Comment: There is one problem. what could be solution now? I have just used `{{userData|json}}` syntax so it is working. But what when I bind `userData` to view, it won't work anymore with `eventemitter` as it has been delayed .

Comment: How do you bind to `userData`?