# How to trigger change detection in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-changedetection

I'm creating a Facebook service that calls the Facebook javascript api and am wondering how to best implement change detection when my values are updated.

I have a `UserService` which has a `currentUser` property that is a BehaviorSubject:

```
currentUser: Subject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(new User(null));
```

And when I want to update the user in response to the facebook javascript sdk telling me the user has logged in or logged out, I update that and need to call `tick()` on an `ApplicationRef`:

```
updateUser(user: User) {
  console.log('UserService.updateUser:', user);
  this.currentUser.next(user);
  this.appRef.tick(); // UI does not update without this
}

constructor(facebook: Facebook) {
  this.facebook.facebookEvents.filter(x => x != null 
         && x.eventName == 'auth.authResponseChange')
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.updateUser(new User(event.data));
      }
}
```

In my component I store the 'currentUser' from the user service in the constructor and bind to the value property:

```
<h2>Logged into Facebook as {{currentUser.value.name}}</h2>
<p>Is this you? &nbsp; <img src="{{currentUser.value.profilePicUrl}}"></p>
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better way than having to call ApplicationRef.tick() after a change triggered from an external library?

### Edit

I tried using NgZone and that doesn't work, using a different event that returns posts in a feed as the service pages through them:

```
constructor(userService: UserService, private ref: ApplicationRef, private zone: NgZone)

...

this.postsSubject.subscribe((post) => {
  this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => { // doesn't do anything
    this.posts.push(post);
    console.log('postsSubject POST, count is ', this.posts.length);
    ref.tick(); // required to update bindings
  });
}
```

The console shows the count incrementing, but the html binding `{{posts.length}}` is only updated if I add the `ref.tick()` call...

I think I saw somewhere that you can make available 'inputs' to any component from the top-level app component which might be the way to go for the logged in user, but not other calls like getting posts in a feed...

Comment: I dont know but if this could help you then fine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500890/eventemitter-in-shared-services-constructor-doenst-emit-data

Comment: currentUser is a BehaviorSubject. You have to subscribe to it using the async pipe `{{ (currentUser | async)?.value?.name}}`.

Answer (score 20):

> Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way than having to call `ApplicationRef.tick()` after a change triggered from an external library?

It depends.  If you're calling the Facebook APIs outside of Angular (i.e., registering asynchronous event handlers outside Angular), then you'll need to manually run change detection as part of handling any events.  You can either

- inject `NgZone` and then call `run()` on that object, which will execute the passed (callback) function inside the Angular zone and then automatically call `ApplicationRef().tick()`, which will run change detection for the entire app, or
- inject `ApplicationRef` and call `tick()` yourself, or
- inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()` yourself -- this will only run change detection on the one component and its children

Note, if you inject `NgZone`, you don't want to use `runOutsideAngular()`.  That will execute the passed (callback) function outside the Angular zone, and it will not call `ApplicationRef().tick()`, so change detection will not execute.

If you call the Facebook APIs inside Angular, you might be able to avoid all of the above, because then Angular (via its use of Zone.js) should monkey-patch the asynchronous event calls.  Then, when your events fire, `ApplicationRef.tick()` will automatically be called. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34593821/215945 for more discussion on this approach.

Comment: So maybe the best way to avoid whole-app change detection would be to use the ChangeDetectorRef for the component and subscribe to the user change event and call it from there?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat, if only one component's view needs to update, then that is probably the most efficient way to do it.  (Note that the component and its children are changed detected with `detectChanges()`. I will update my answer.)

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if it's better. There a couple of other ways I can think of.

### Using NgZone

You can inject NgZone and execute the run method with a callback:

```
 NgZone.run(()=>this.currentUser.next(user));
```

### Using setTimeout

setTimeout will trigger change detection automatically:

```
setTimeout(()=>this.currentUser.next(user));
```

Comment: The right one is ngZone, we had similar issue with GoogleMaps placing pins on the map.

Comment: you can't use `NgZone.run`, one must inject its instance.

Comment: And Using setTimeout is not right, it only trigger the outterZone(aka Zone.current) of instance of NgZone. So it will not trigger angular's change detection.

Comment: @e-cloud, are you sure about that? setTimeout most definitely runs inside the Angular zone (forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior) and upon leaving drains the micro/macro tasks and triggers change detection.

Answer (score 5):

Could you give us the way you initialize the `Facebook` provider and you your service in your component?

**Option #1**

Your behavior makes me change that the Facebook code is running outside an Angular zone, so Angular change detection doesn't run when an event fires. You

You could also run manually the change detection:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  someMethod() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

See these questions:

- ["async" pipe not rendering the stream updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513015/async-pipe-not-rendering-the-stream-updates)
- [How to force a component's re-rendering in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105374/how-to-force-a-components-re-rendering-in-angular-2/35106069#35106069)

**Option #2**

Perhaps you event is fired before the component register a callback on the `currentUser` subject. In this case, you could trigger the event later...