# Force update *ngFor Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

For my app I need to force update the *ngFor component.

Any way to force update it from my code for example with a updateList function?

I'm using a firebasepipe to get the child_added event to update the ngfor. I need to remove an entry and add an entry at the same time but it only updates things that get added.

```
<li *ngFor="#quote of firebaseUrl | firebaseevent:'child_added'"> <strong>"{{quote.text}}"</strong> </li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by force update? The ngFor block is updated when adding and removing elements... Do you want to update when updating the content of a particular element?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I want to update it from an FireBase link, I used the https://github.com/sararob/angular2base and need to add and remove a entry at the same time. Now it only gets updated if something gets added.

Comment: I can't really tell without seeing a code example but it sounds like a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520018/how-to-trigger-change-detection-in-angular2

Comment: `<li *ngFor="#quote of firebaseUrl | firebaseevent:'child_added'">
            <strong>"{{quote.text}}"</strong>
        </li>`

Comment: isn't the child_added filter making it so you only get the child_added event? and not the child_removed?

Comment: Uhm, well I think so. But I don't know how to make a child_removed pipe :(

Comment: firebaseevent:'child_added':'child_removed' ?

Comment: Uhm, I'll post the pipe:

Comment: Looking at the pipe implementation here it sounds like the thing to do https://github.com/sararob/angular2base/blob/master/src/firebasepipe.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104099/discussion-between-toskv-and-anned20).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the **firebaseevent** pipe does not listen to the 'child_removed' event.

You can add child_removed to the arguments given to the pipe:

```
<li *ngFor="#quote of firebaseUrl | firebaseevent:'child_added':'child_removed'"> <strong>"{{quote.text}}"</strong> </li>
```

Note: after a long chat with OP we determined that angular2base does not properly support the 'child_removed' event.

Comment: `Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at column 72 in expression [ngFor #quote of firebaseUrl | firebaseevent:'child_added':'child_removed] ("
    </div>
    <ul class="messages-list">
        <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="#quote of firebaseUrl | firebaseevent:'child_added':'child_removed">
            <strong>"{{"): MessageList@11:12`

Comment: you are missing a ' at the end of child_removed :P

Comment: I updated the question to use the entire code example to prevent copy errors.

Comment: Well, now I don't have any errors, but it still doesn't work when a child is removed.

Comment: I think the problem is in github.com/sararob/angular2base/blob/master/src/firebasepipe.ts itself. It doesn't have anything regarding `child_removed` in it