# Angular2 Forms - ngControl

Tags: forms, angular

I'm trying to use `ngControl` to apply error classes based on user's input.

Somehow, I can't make it to work. I see that appropriate classes are set (line ng-invalid), but when trying to use `name.valid` (where `name` is my ngControl) it doesn't work.

html:

```
   <div ngClass="{alert: name.invalid}">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input ngControl="name" #name id="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name"/>
   </div> 

</div>
```

js

```
export class App {
   userForm: any;
   user: any;

   constructor(
     private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

     this.user = {name: 'Ben'};
     this.userForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        'name': ['', Validators.required]
     });
   }

}
```

I saw on angular.io examples that they do use it like this (just for other cases, like show/hide `divs`)?

Here's the simple plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BKx4yplIOu44tk7Mfolc?p=preview

When input field is empty, I would expect that upper `div` gets `alert` class, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: Please insert a reduced code sample in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there are three things to change in your template:

- `ngClass` should be `[ngClass]`. Otherwise the value is considered as a string and not as an expression.
- `#name` should be `#name="ngForm"`. Otherwise you reference the DOM element and not the control.
- there is no `invalid` property on controls in Angular2 but only a `valid` one.

Here is the refactored code:

```
<div [ngClass]="{alert: !name.valid}">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input ngControl="name" #name="ngForm"
      required id="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name"/>
</div>
```

Here is the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/OJfb9VDqlrRH4oHXQJyg?p=preview.

Note that you can't leverage of `FormBuilder` with `ngControl` since the latter allows you to define inline form. With `FormBuilder` you must use `ngFormControl` instead.

Here is a sample:

```
<div [ngClass]="{alert: !userForm.controls.name.valid}">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input [ngFormControl]="userForm.controls.name"
      id="name" [(ngModel)]="user.name"/>
</div>
```

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried so many combinations, that finally I made some typos. But you made some things clear, and I see it's working now. I only have one more question. I see in console that this exception is thrown: `Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Expression '{alert: !name.valid} in App@4:7' has changed after it was checked.` I see it in my app, and that's why I started with all the changes and workarounds, and finally ended up here. Do you have an idea, how it should be fixed (in my app, it happens with combination of name.valid and name.touched).

Comment: You're welcome! I think that you could try to call the `detectChanges` method of `ChangeDetectorRef` within the `ngOnInit` method of your component. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520018/how-to-trigger-change-detection-in-angular2/35520764#35520764.