# Loading Angular 2 Component in a DOM element created after rendering

Tags: angular, typescript, arcgis-js-api

Using Angular 2.0 (final), how can I load a `Component` inside of a DOM element created by a non-Angular library, after app bootstrapping and Component rendering has occurred?

> I had previously used `DynamicComponentLoader.loadNextToLocation()` to load Components inside of DOM elements, but that was deprecated as of RC5.

**The Problem (TL;DR)**

I'm attempting to use Angular 2.0 to insert a dynamically-created Component inside of a popup window that is generated at runtime by an external, non-Angular library (specifically, an `InfoWindow/Popup` for an ESRI `ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.x` Map).

Since the popup window is generated entirely by the external library *after* app `bootstrap` and the parent Component's `ngAfterViewInit()/ngAfterContentInit()` events occur, any `#ref` tag present in the newly-added popup's DOM is ignored. And without a `#ref` tag and the derived `ViewContainerRef`, I can't figure out how to insert new Components inside of the popup.

#### The Code

I'm using the same setup shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044960/2432724), namely:

```
@ViewChild('dynamicContentPlaceHolder', {read: ViewContainerRef})
protected dynamicComponentTarget: ViewContainerRef;

// this will be reference to dynamic content - to be able to destroy it
protected componentRef: ComponentRef<IHaveDynamicData>;

this.compiler
.compileComponentAsync<IHaveDynamicData>(dynamicType, MyModule)
.then((factory: ng.ComponentFactory<IHaveDynamicData>) =>
{
    // our component will be inserted after #dynamicContentPlaceHolder
    this.componentRef = this.dynamicComponentTarget.createComponent(factory,     0);

    // and here we have access to our dynamic component
    let component: IHaveDynamicData = this.componentRef.instance;

    component.entity = this.entity;
});
```

> Note: Based on @MarkRajcok's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35527334/2432724), I had the idea to try `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to trigger a re-render of the parent Component, with the hope that a `#ref` tag in the newly-created popup's DOM would be picked up and compiled. But, likely due to my inexperience with Angular 2.0, I've so far had no luck. Perhaps this a misguided approach all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did this, but it feels like a total hack... it did render the component at the dom element location, though

```
var me = this;
setTimeout(function(){ 
  var simpleComponent = me.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SimpleComponent);
  me.componentRef = me.dynamicTarget.createComponent(simpleComponent);
                var node = document.getElementById("theTest");
                node.appendChild(me.componentRef['_hostElement'].nativeElement);
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Marc. While this isn't an Angular-friendly way of doing things, I simply can't figure out how else to accomplish my goal. Cheers!

Comment: just add maybe a parent <div class="main-container"><div class="hidden" #dynamicTarget></div>. I would just hide the #dynamicTarget since the new created components will populate next to #dynamicTarget. I guess having 1 useless hidden element is better than manipulating your DOM with javascript append.